# Connection string in UseSqlServer

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ado.net

I am working on Visual Studio Code and I added EntitiyFramework.Design, EntitiyFramework.SqlServer packages.

However, I got an error message as below when I utilize my UseSqlServer().

```
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseLoggerFactory(MyLoggerFactory)
                .UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=(localdb)/MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=ShopDb;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
        }
```

My error messege is as below:

[image]

Also I removed my Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer package --version 5.0.0 and then added its --version 3.1.3. However this problem did not solved.

I shared my ConsoleApp.csproj as below:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.0">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

As a result, I cannot run my .UseSqlServer() method.

Is my connection string wrong?

What should I do to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: ADO.NET connection strings aren't affected by the libraries that use them. EF is just a library that uses ADO.NET underneath. Server instance names use `\ ` not `/`. The correct instance name is `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB`. In the connection string you should escape the backslash `Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB`

Comment: BTW post the error message, not a link to an image of the error message. You can select text in a console window and copy it. Instead of a screenshot, post the actual command you used and the actual error

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/ **errors** when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mistype in the command. Instead of `and` should be `add` (in the command line).

`dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate`